# React won't load images or their alt text

Tags: reactjs

I'm doing a portfolio tutorial and have *supposedly* copied it line for line but I can't get it to render the images. React doesn't load images or their alt text.

***Sandbox.io: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-wont-load-images-41toos***

**index.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
  
);
```

**App.js**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.scss'; 
import Layout from './components/Layout';

function App() {
  return (
    <>
        <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Layout />} />
        </Routes>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

**Layout**

```
import Sidebar from './../Sidebar';
import './index.scss';

const Layout = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <Sidebar />
        </>
    )
};

export default Layout
```

**Sidebar**

```
import './index.scss';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import LogoS from '../../assets/images/logo-s.png';
import LogoSubtitle from '../../assets/images/logo_sub.png';

const Sidebar = () => {
    <div className="nav-bar">
        <Link className="logo" to="/">
            <img src={LogoS} alt="logo" />
            <img src={LogoSubtitle} alt="slobodan" /> 
        </Link>
    </div>
}

export default Sidebar
```

**Project Tree**:

```
src
   --- assets
      --- images
         --- logo-s.png
          --- logo_sub.png
   --- components
      --- layout
      --- sidebar
   --- app.js
   --- index.js
```

I'm sorry if I haven't posted the question the right way, I'm new to react.

Comment: What errors do you see in the [React dev tools](https://reactjs.org/blog/2019/08/15/new-react-devtools.html#how-do-i-get-the-new-devtools) or your browsers developer console?

Comment: Could you share your snippet via https://codesandbox.io/ ?

Comment: @Peppermintology I dont see any errors. When I log the images they appear in the static folder as they should.

Comment: @JanezKuhar
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-wont-load-images-41toos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I forgot to add `return` in the **sidebar** component. Check your syntax people.